# App Crashes when I add a Control Point to an Array in Cocos2D-X

Tags: arrays, crash, point, cocos2d-x

Ok. Either I'm missing something really obvious, or I'm not understand what a control point is. Here's a function I call to create an array made of several points. I'll use these points later to place sprites on a grid.

```
void gMode::createGrid(){
    _grid = new CCPointArray;
    for (int y=1; y<=25; y++) {
        for (int x = 2; x<=29; x++){
            CCPoint point = CCPointMake(x, y);
        _grid->addControlPoint(point);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You need to create the CCPointArray ....say CCPointArray::create(100) and then perform whatever you want to ...tell me the results